# Bitbang I²C to multiple slaves with same address

Tags: gpio, i2c, bit-bang

I want to use I²C to read several identical sensors with hardcoded addresses. Reading sequential is not an option. Neither is a multiplexer. Both for reading speed reasons.

Is there any issue with bit-banging a common SCL line and reading SDA over several GPIO pins?
I know clock stretching might be an issue but if I just wait until all slaves release the SCL line it should work?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of this approach on the Pi.

If clock stretching is not a issue I don't see why it could not work.

I suggest you look at extending an I2C sniffer I wrote to test the idea.

http://pigpio/examples.html#Python_I2C_sniffer

Note that you can have multiple software I2C buses on the Pi (you need two spare GPIO per bus).